# How to make the material-ui stepper like a sticky horizontal menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI stepper and wanted to see if I am able to have the stepper stick to the top of the page just below the AppBar, while scrolling down the page.

I have the following style and stepper code. I tried `postion: fixed` but this didn't work.

```
  stepper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 0, 5),
    backgroundColor: '#EAEFF1',
    zIndex: 1,
    color: '#fff',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: fixed,
    top: 30
  },
  stepIcon: {
    transform: "scale(1.5)",
    "font-size": "50px"
  },

                <React.Fragment>
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} className={classes.stepper} alternativeLabel>
                        {steps.map(label => (
                          <Step key={label}>
                            <StepLabel
                                classes={{
                                  alternativeLabel: classes.alternativeLabel,
                                  active: classes.alternativeLabelActive,
                                  iconContainer: classes.stepIcon
                                }}
                            >
                              {label}
                            </StepLabel>
                          </Step>
                        ))}
                    </Stepper>
                  </Grid>
                </React.Fragment>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the `Stepper` right below the `AppBar`, you can wrap the `Stepper` component inside a separate `AppBar` component, and set the upper margin of that `AppBar` to `theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight`. Check out this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-glade-y8vzj?file=/index.js) for a working example.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me as I currently have my `classes.stepper` within my `<Stepper />` component. Moving this up to the `<AppBar>` then breaks my stepper and it's full width and unfortunately all messed up, which I don't want. Is there anyways of keeping what I have above within my stepper class but with the AppBar?

Comment: Hey, I've modified the CodeSandbox. I removed the AppBar and tried to preserve most of your styles in the Stepper component itself. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Definitely much better so thanks for revamping your example but just have the following two queries: 1) the content I have below the stepper such as a sub-heading on the page is now below the `<Stepper/>` section and is no longer visible. Is there a way to give the stepper section a height and then have existing content, sub-heading pushed down so not cut off by stepper? 2) Is there a way so that the stepper is actually condensed and lined up nicely centered in the page and not take up the whole 100% width, that is vertical guttering on both the left and right hand sides?

Comment: Yeah, I've updated the CodeSandbox again. For (1), I used a ref to keep track of the Stepper's height (I'm sure this is not the best approach), added a Toolbar below the AppBar, and removed the marginTop. For (2), I added CSS transforms to move it to the center. If this helped, do mark the question as solved by accepting this answer.